What types of outputs apart from Open Drain/Open Collector exist?
I am trying to grasp the idea of an Open Circuit/Open Drain, but I haven't been able to find, which other types of outputs exist ("Closed Circuits", so to speak). It would be helpful, if you provided some examples.

I've little interest in providing a survey. But there are push pull (2-quadrant) outputs like are found in HC logic, pseudo push-pull like traditional TTL which sources a lot less than it sinks, and current-type outputs like ECL, to name a few. And that's just logic. Since you don't limit your question to logic, then there are a nearly unlimited array. This way beyond my interest. Perhaps someone else will take this on. ;)

@periblepsis thank you, that's already really helpful

Does Trying to understand push-pull output mode and open-drain output mode in a MCU's GPIO pin help? That includes a diagram of a GPIO for a STM32H7xx MCU.

I'l first define what it means to "source" and to "sink" current. Imagine that the boxes below are some digital circuit or IC that is able to produce a high or a low output potential, with respect to ground:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Whether a digital circuit/IC can sink or source current depends entirely on the architecture of its output driver. In the above examples, the IC produces a high output by effectively connecting that output to the positive supply. To output low it must connect that output to ground, or its negative supply. This is what will determine the voltage at the output, and ultimately the direction of current.
On the left, current is being "pushed" out of the output. On the right, current is being "pulled" into the input. This gives rise to the term "push-pull" in the context of output cabilities.
If an output is called "push-pull", it normally means that there are a pair of transistors being used to control which supply terminal is effectively connected to the output:

simulate this circuit
Here I've used BJTs, but these transistors could also be FETs. The transistors are switched by controlling their bases/gates so that only one of them is conductive at a time. You may think of the transistors as switches (shown middle and right), connecting the output to either the positive or negative supply, depending on which switch is closed. The middle circuit's output is high, the right-hand circuit output is low.
All of the above are "push-pull"-style outputs. They can all both sink and source current from/to any load connected to them.
There exists a class of outputs that can only sink current, called "open-collector" or "open-drain". They consist of only the lower transistor in the push-pull pair, and are consequently only able to pull current into their output. For some reason we don't call them "pull-only" outputs, but that would be a good name:

simulate this circuit
Being restricted to sinking current, only able to force their output low, they have no means of bringing their output high. They rely on whatever's connected to the output to do the "pulling up" of potential, and therefore you will almost always see a "pull-up" resistor (R1 and R2 above) or something else to raise the output potential. These "pull-up" elements do the job of the upper transistors in push-pull outputs, but in a passive manner.
There are a couple of huge benefits, and one big disadvantage. The down-side is that since you are relying on a resistor (or other resistive element) to source current passively, that resistance combined with any capacitance present at the output will slow the output's rising transistion significantly; on the rising edge, the system effectively becomes a low-pass RC filter, with the output potential slewing upwards much more slowly than a near-zero ohm transistor could achieve.
The first benefit is that an IC powered with, say, +5V, can produce a 0V (low) output, or almost any arbitrarily high output potential:

simulate this circuit
By connecting a different supply potential at the top of the "pull-up" element, you get to choose what potential is "high", making it trivially easy to interface logic systems of different voltages.
The second big advantage is that you can literally connect open-drain/collector outputs directly together:

simulate this circuit
If any one of those transistors is "on", then the output is held low, but if they are all "off" then the output is high. This arrangement is called "wire-AND", since all outputs must be high for the overall output to be high.
You can't connect push-pull outputs together like this, because if any two such outputs have different values then there's effectively a short circuit between the two supply rails; both are pushing/pulling equally hard in opposite directions, and something will pop.
Wire-AND is very useful for serial data buses like I2C, where there are several open-collector/drain devices all sharing the same data line.
The famous and wonderful LM393 dual comparator IC has open-collector outputs, which you can see in the internal schematic shown on page 2 of the LM393 datasheet. That means you can connect their outputs together, but you must provide an external pull-up resistor:

simulate this circuit
Here, even though the comparators are powered from +5V, the output \$V_{OUT}\$ will be 0V or +12V. The output will be high (+12V) only if both comparator outputs are high, and low (0V) otherwise.

Wow, a fantastic answer! Thank you!

When you mention the +5V powered IC can be interfaced with any higher voltage, I would add the caveat that you’re still subjected to the absolute maximum ratings of the pin on the IC. With the LM393 example it works great since the max is 36V, but you can’t typically do this with modern MCUs and FPGAs…unless they say explicitly it’s OK to continuously engage the protection diode (if there is an upper one).

Normal outputs are called "push-pull" or "totem-pole", they can push current out for logic high output voltage level, and pull current in for logic low output voltage level.
If you omit the "push" part and can only "pull", that's the most common version of open-collector/open-drain.
It's basically the same than when you use an actual trasistor and drive the load with the collector/drain.
(some open-collector types are pushing high to source current and can't pull low, but for getting the concept, it does not matter).

Many thanks! Here where you mention "driving the load" with the collector/drain, do you mean using a BJT to let the current flow to the load?

@Andrew'sQuest BJTs have a collector, FETs have a drain. Yes I meant transistors.
